# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Rule - missing Actions "defer delivery by"

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop

Using COM Reference... to local MS Outlook 2019 (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook) I want to have:

[img outlook rules defer delivery by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk7SQ.jpg)

(Create a rule for all messages sent - delaying sending by 1 minute.)

Currently my code looks like this:

```
string ruleName = "rules defer delivery by 1 min";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Rules rules = null;
try
{
    rules = OutlookApplication.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Error:({ex.Message})");
    return;
}
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Rule rule = rules.Create(ruleName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuleType.olRuleSend);
rule.Name = ruleName;
rule.Conditions.From.Enabled = false;
rule.Conditions.Subject.Enabled = false;
//help needed here... rule.Actions.... (defer delivery by)
rule.Enabled = true;
try
{
    rules.Save(true);
    MessageBox.Show($"success role creation ({ruleName})");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Error:({ex.Message})");
}
```

I only got part of the result because I don't know how to add the right action:

[img comparison of manual and program mode] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzRBT.jpg)

Can anyone help me add "defer deliveries by 1 minutes" in the code or know any other solution to the problem of automatically creating such a rule?

(this is my first post here please forgive me).

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionType` is `28 (OlRuleActionType.olRuleActionDefer)`.

That kind of action can be accessed from the `Rule.Actions` collection (when you enumerate the collection), but it cannot be created programmatically: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff868996(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

When accessing the action, you won't be able to read its parameters (number of minutes to defer). If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it allows to access the parameters, but it won't let you create [such an action](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOClientRuleAction.htm#RDOClientDeferDeliveryRuleAction) either (planned for a future version).